# ng-click outside form dosen't get data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

click i dosen't get the form data when button is outside form

code

```
<ion-view title="Indstillinger">

<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button class="button" form="userForm" ng-click="update()">
        Gem
    </button>
</ion-nav-buttons>


<ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
    <form id="userForm">

        <ion-list>


            <label class="item item-input" name="navn">
                <span class="input-label">Navn</span>
                <input type="text"  placeholder={{user.name}}  ng-model="name">
            </label>


        </ion-list>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

i tried add form id to form and button, but i still dosen't get the form data on ngclick :/

update:

```
 $scope.update = function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    })
```

Comment: show your javascript , and show enough of your HTML to include ng-app and ng-controller or whatever related ng attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ion-content creates a child scope.  The input element is setting the "name" property on this scope, not the scope being used in the ion-nav-buttons section.

This is the classic "dot notation" issue in Angular.

If you are using an "outer" controller:

```
<div ng-controller="outer as vm">
    <ion-view title="Indstillinger">

    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button" form="userForm" ng-click="update()">
            Gem
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>


    <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
        <form id="userForm">

            <ion-list>


                <label class="item item-input" name="navn">
                    <span class="input-label">Navn</span>
                    <input type="text"  placeholder={{user.name}}  ng-model="vm.name">
                </label>


            </ion-list>
        </form>
    </ion-content>
</div>

.controller('outer', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        name: "Joe"
    }
    $scope.update = function()
    {
        console.log($scope.vm.name);
    }
})
```

Comment: that and the fact that he didn't even reference a controller in his HTML , which will also make code not function

Comment: ohhhh ,   I have no clue what ion is ,  I could be worng there , you'd know better

Comment: I suspect the OP is just leaving the outer controller out for his own reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use:

```
console.log($scope.name);
```

instead of:

```
console.log(this.name);
```

Comment: still dosen't get the form value

Comment: I already asked OP to show code ,   as far as I can tell this answer is correct, unless OP would like to create a fiddle example or elaborate more with the actual code that is breaking this

Comment: $scope.update is the only thing in controller besides scope user

Answer (score 0):

since you didn't post the rest of HTML or the rest of controller code , this is the only answer I can possibly provide

```
 $scope.update = function() {
        console.log($scope.name);
    })
```

I know you said that it doesn't work , but that code is in fact valid and does work.  Something else that you refused to post is breaking

Did you check console for errors? I'm sure there are some, did you confirm that angular is properly loaded, did you properly set add `ng-app` and `ng-controller` ?

Comment: $scope.update is the only thing in controller besides scope.user...
and this is all html for this form..
so all code need'ed is here

Answer (score 0):

1) Try moving your `<button ng-click="update">` outside of your `<ion-nav-buttons>` container and see if it works.

2) If it works, read this: [Transcluding ng-click in a directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940766/transcluding-ng-click-in-a-directive)