# Handling click on transcluded content of an angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

So lets say I have a directive that looks like so:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('foo', foo);

    /* @ngInject */
    function foo() {
        var directive =  {
            restrict : 'E',
            controller: controller,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            link: link,
            transclude : true,
            replace : true,
            bindToController: true,
            scope: {},
            template : '<div><div ng-transclude></div>'
        };

        return directive;

        function controller() {
            var vm = this;
            vm.click = function () {
                // do something, add class whatever
            }
        }
        function link(scope, elem, attrs) {}
    }



}());
```

Now if I use the directive like so:

```
<foo>
   <button ng-click="vm.click()">Click me!</button>
</foo>
```

I wanted to access the click function of the directive, how do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transcluding ng-click in a directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940766/transcluding-ng-click-in-a-directive)

Answer (score 0):

The transcluded contents scope is not created as a child of it's directives scope if there directive itself is defined with an isolated scope.

See:
[Why ng-transclude's scope is not a child of its directive's scope - if the directive has an isolated scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788289/why-ng-transcludes-scope-is-not-a-child-of-its-directives-scope-if-the-direc)

As such kwan245's answer is correct for your particular example.

Answer (score -1):

remove `scope: {}` from directive declaration and it should works.

Comment: Please try adding more details on how that answer could provide a solution to the problem. That way, the OP (and anybody else) will be able to get a better understanding of your answer.